# If command returns nothing, then print/echo a statement to STDOUT in csh shell

Tags: unix, printing, null, stdout, tcsh

I grep for a word/pattern in a file, if such a pattern doesn't exist in a file, then I want to print/echo "-". Can we do this on command line in a single lined command?

```
grep word <file> | <command to return "-" if "word" not present in file>
```

Similarly if script returns nothing , echo "-"

```
python script.py | <command to return "-" if script returns nothing/NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check that there is no output for a command regardless of its returncode then you should check that there is no output, one way of doing that is:

```
 awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) print "-"}'
```

So for example:

```
$ grep - /dev/null | awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) print "-"}'
-
$ echo some output | awk '{print} END {if (NR == 0) print "-"}'
some output
```

Comment: Only works for me if I delete the `$` prefixing `NR`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by following command:

```
grep word file.txt ||  echo "-"
```

If word is present in file then it will print the line from file else will print `-`.

If command is script then:

```
ret=`python script.py`; if [[ "$ret" ]];then echo "$ret"; else echo "-"; fi
```

Comment: Thank you .. it worked! how can we do the same if script returns nothing, echo it .. example .. python script.py | <command to return "-" if script returns nothing!

Comment: Something like `python script.py || echo "-"` you should try.

Comment: Great!! I just checked, the command you given for script  worked for bash  shell. Looking it for c shell?